# simulating trade reconciliation - one-to-one match of two sets with acceptable variation in items

Tags: python, datetime, set

I am trying to simulate a trade reconciliation. Say I have two sets like below, set A is the trading record from a trading capital and set B is the record from all exchanges.

The letter represents the product exchanged, number represents quantity exchanged, and the timestamp represents the time it is recorded. I need to write a program to check if there is an one-to-one match of the trade records in the two sets.

However, the catch is that the record timestamp of the exchange is within 5 minutes of one of the trading record from the capital, it is considered a match.

For example, ('A', '10', '12:01:00') in setA(capital) can match to ('A', '10', '11:59:00') or ('A', '10', '12:00:00') in setB(exchange)

The output should be a boolean value of whether there is an one-to-one match.
Below should output False.

I've tried to match them one by one by using two loops, but I think I'm encountering some issues. What is a way to best do this?

```
setA = {('H', '-50', '16:19:02'), ('A', '10', '11:53:00'), 
('A', '10', '11:59:00'), ('A', '10', '12:00:00'), ('B', '12', '15:01:02')} 

setB = {('A', '10', '12:01:00'), ('H', '-50', '16:14:02'), 
('A', '10', '11:59:00'), ('A', '10', '12:00:00'), ('B', '12', '15:01:03')}
```

```
    if len(self.setA) != self.setB:
        return False
    exchange_visited = set()
    for a_product, a_qty, a_timestamp in self.setA:
        reconciliation = False
        for exchange_product, exchange_qty, exchange_timestamp in self.setB:
            a_time = datetime.strptime(a_timestamp, '%H:%M:%S')
            exchange_time = datetime.strptime(exchange_timestamp, '%H:%M:%S')
            if (exchange_product, exchange_qty, exchange_timestamp) not in exchange_visited:
                if a_product == e_product and a_qty == exchange_qty and abs(a_time - exchange_time) <= timedelta(minutes=5):
                    reconciliation = True
                    exchange_visited.add((exchange_product, exchange_qty, exchange_timestamp))
                    break
        if not found_reconciliation:
            return False
    return reconciliatoin
```

Comment: You're missing a few commas in there

Comment: Please share the code of your attempt, what you expected to happen and what happened instead - people will be able to help from there. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask (also note that the 'number' you're referring to in the tuples is actually still a string, in quotes, so whatever you do will need to convert that)

Comment: Edit: I added my attempt to the post